# Show time in HH:MM on Xaxis Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, highcharts

I'm using PHP, Javascript and Highcharts Library.

I need to print in the Yaxis the evolution of the temperature and on Xaxis the time in HH:MM.

The format of var "$fecha" is this:

> Wed Aug 09 2017 14:47:01 GMT+0200 (Hora de verano romance)

The format of var "$dateProc" is this:

> 1502283181000

My code is this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
           <!-- Importo el archivo Javascript de Highcharts directamente desde su servidor -->
      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

      <script>
      myChart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
              title: {
                  text: 'Temperatura in the Office'
              },
              xAxis: {
                  type: 'datetime',
                  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                        minute: '%H:%M',
                        hour: '%H:%M'
                  }
              },
              yAxis: {
                  title: {
                      text: 'TEMPERATURA'
                  }
              },
              series: [{
                  name: 'TIEMPO',
                  data:(
                    function(){
                      var data = [];
                      <?php  for($i = count($rawdata)-1; $i>=0;$i--){ ?>
                        var $fecha = new Date("<?php echo $rawdata[$i]->fechaHora;?>");
                        $dateProc = $fecha.getTime();

                      data.push(['$dateProc',<?php echo $rawdata[$i]->temperatura;?>]);
                      <?php } ?>
                    return data;
                  })()
              }]
            });
   </script>
```

And the result this:

[graphic result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI8Sv.png)

My problem is that in the Xaxis don't show the separators info in HH:MM.

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?
Cause the time is printed in a strange way

Comment: Are you sure your date is formated correctly? Using your chart replacing the PHP with some sample dates it works as you expect it to: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jx3hw7ht/). I would suggest you do a `console.log(data)` before returning it in your data function to verify the data.

Comment: Yes, you're right!
I'm using date with the string format and viewing your example I see that you use data like an integer.
Thank for all.
You solved my problem!

Comment: Great, I will write a short answer so that it is there if anyone searches in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you do the following

```
 data.push(['$dateProc',<?php echo $rawdata[$i]->temperatura;?>]);
```

Which means that the data in the array ends up looking like this:

```
['time', temperature]
```

When it should in fact look like this

```
[time, temperature]
```

That is, time should be an `integer`, not a `string`.